# How to make more buttons work using HandleButtonAction and if-statements

Tags: if-statement, button, javafx, scenebuilder

I have managed to get 2 buttons working using an if and else statement. if i add another if/else statement the program no longer works. How can i add more statements so that other buttons in my GUI work? I have about 7 more buttons to code

```
 package finalgui;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;   
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXMLDocumentController{

@FXML
private Button btnViewSPC;
@FXML
private Button btnBack;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
Stage stage;
Parent root;
if(event.getSource()==btnViewSPC) {
    //get reference to the button's stage
    stage=(Stage) btnViewSPC.getScene().getWindow();
    //load up next scene
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("addviewdel.fxml"));
}
else{
    stage=(Stage) btnBack.getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FinalGUI.fxml"));
}
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you could use multiple `if` statements to destinguish multiple buttons

```
Object source = event.getSource();
if (source == button1) {
    ...
} else if (source == button2) {
     ...
} else if (source == button2) {
     ...
}
...
else {
     ...
}
```

However personally I'd prefer associating the data with the `Button` using the `userData` property:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    btnViewSPC.setUserData("addviewdel.fxml");
    btnViewSPC.setUserData("FinalGUI.fxml");
    ...
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Node source = (Node) event.getSource();

    Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(source.getUserData().toString()));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

---

Or alternatively use different methods to handle the events from different buttons. You can still add a "helper method" to the controller to avoid repeating all the code:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction1(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    showStage(event, "addviewdel.fxml");
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction2(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    showStage(event, "FinalGUI.fxml");
}

...

private void showStage(ActionEvent event, String fxmlResource) throws IOException {
    Node source = (Node) event.getSource();

    Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlResource));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```